# 401 error while trying to connect to a Https url from Java

Tags: java, json, basic-authentication, httpsurlconnection

I tried to access a https url using the HttpsURLConnection class with the username and password(base64 encoded) passed to it.

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");  
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+userPassword);
```

It worked correctly when the username and password were hardcoded in the code.

However, when I stored the username, encrypted `pwd`, and `url` in json format in DB  and tried to fetch them and connect to it, a 401 error is thrown. Printing values from DB show that the values are correct.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();  
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(dbjson);  
String url= jsonObject.get("url").toString().replace('"', ' ').trim();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis was fixed by using org.json.JSONObject to read the String JSON and .getString("") to retrieve the values.